# Java Serverlet Request Parameters Null

Tags: java, jsp, webserver, http-post, server

I am working on a simple java serverlet. It seems as if the server is not getting the parameters. This is my doPost() code.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String a = request.getParameter("a");
        String b = request.getParameter("b");
        System.out.println("I started doing something " + a + " " + b);

    }
```

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>AutoPresServerlet</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>Main</display-name>
<servlet-name>Main</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.altechwebdesign.java.autopres.Main</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Main</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Main</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I am using the Advanced Rest Client for Chrome to send the POST Requests.

Answer (score 0):

you need a form or jsp page to carry html input type values and trigger a servlet.

 then only your servlet can get the value
i would suggest to write form code in `index.jsp` and **call action /Main** from the `form`.
flow should be like

***index.jsp->submitform->main servlet***

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the evidence you have shown use explains why the parameters are null.

> It seems as if the server is not getting the parameters.

I assume that means that you have evidence that your `doPost` method is actually being called.  That points to the fact that the web.xml is correctly directing the request to your servlet code.

That implies that the reason the parameters are not showing up is that they have not been provided (correctly).  But that is happening in the client code and/or the request that it is sending, and you haven't shown that to us.

(It is also possible that you don't have any evidence and your *"if seems ..."* is just a guess.  If that is the case, you need to FIND OUT what is going on, and/or show us the evidence that you actually have.)

I also don't see why you have mentioned JSPs here.  You haven't shown us any JSP code, and it is unlikely that it will be directly relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Servlet can get parameter in your code if and only if your action is triggered with the following data(no matter Get or Post)
***a=test_for_a&b=test_for_b***

you can add some input/select/textarea ***with name***(which would be the parameter name you use in servlet,namely a and b).

Well, ajax would be another solution, which is out of our scope, I bet.

Answer (score 0):

you can test if the request & response working correctly by : 
PrintWriter writer=response.getWriter();
 writer.write("This is my post"); ,
you must have a html form for submitting a & b values. check there action and methods are correct,or restart the server and try again..